# Android Studio RelativeLayout ScrollView icon overrapping text views

Tags: android, android-studio, scrollview, whitespace, android-relativelayout

am trying to press the (instagram, gmail and twitter icons) to occupy the remaining space below the (Email TextView) but every time i run the code on a device, these icons appear floating over the texts views when scrolling, where could have gone wrong, here's the code. Regards.

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/bg1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:alpha=".60"
    android:rotation="360"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/bg1"/>

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/frn"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="35dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/frn"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/bio"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/frn"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="BIOGRAPHY:"
            android:textSize="25sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/bio"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="NAME: Frank Leons Malisawa"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/usr"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/name"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="USERNAME: Frinno"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/hby"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/usr"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="HOBBIES: Swimming, Art, Adveture."
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cntct"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/hby"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="CONTACT: +255 684 999 505"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/cntct"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text="EMAIL: frinno.frasha@gmail.com"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/insta"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/insta"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/twit"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/insta"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/twit"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/gm"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/twit"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/gmail"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Can you post a picture of your result?

Comment: where you want your `Imageview` ?

Answer (score 0):

Add layout_below attribute to the Image views and set to to appear below email text view like this:

```
<ImageView
                android:id="@+id/insta"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/email"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                android:src="@drawable/insta"/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`, use  `android:layout_below="@id/email"` in the imageViews